# Quadratic inequalities

Tags: inequality, quadratics

[image]

[image]

This is what I tried. I tried finding limits of y and then equating them with the given limits, but I could not simplify it further. The given options for this question are:

1. a+b=23
2. a^2+b^2=277
3. a+b=17
4. a^2=b^2=149

Comment: There are loads of $a$ and $b$ that lets $-5 \leq y \leq 4$, for instance $a = b = 0$ yields a $y$ with maximum value of $1.5$ and minimum value of $0$, while $a = 1, b = 1/4$ gives you a function spanning the range of $[0,\: 9/8]$. If you want $y$ to actually _reach_ the bounds of $-5$ and $4$ at some point, then that's another question entirely.

Comment: I want the values of a and b such that the minimum value of y is -5 and maximum value is 4.

Comment: In that case, differentiation is your friend. (Differentiation should be the automatic response the _moment_ anyone mentions any of the phrases "minimum value", "maximum value", "extreme value", or any other word signifying such. There might in some special cases be more elegant ways to go about it, but I don't think this is one of them.)

Comment: Please explain how to begin..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want $-5 \le \dfrac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3}\le 4$ for all real $x$.

Noting $x^2+2x+3 = (x+1)^2+2 > 0$, we can multiply with this throughout to get
$$-5x^2-10x-15 \le x^2 + ax + b \le 4x^2+8x + 12$$

Now take the left inequality, and we have 
$6x^2+(a+10) x+(15+b) \ge 0$.  As this needs to hold true for all real $x$, we can set a condition that the discriminant should never be positive.  However if you also want equality to hold for some value of x, we want the discriminant to be zero. So $(a+10)^2 = 24(15+b)$ is one condition.

Similarly, looking at the right inequality, we have
$3x^2 + (8-a)x+(12-b) \ge 0$, so the discriminant condition gives us $(8-a)^2 = 12(12-b)$.

Thus we have the two equations to solve for $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. Solving these, we have $(a, b) = (14, 9)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to be familiar with derivatives for this answer to make any sense. If you do not know how to differentiate a fraction like this one, then perhaps this is not the intended approach. If you're not more or less fluent in the use of derivatives, then I might suggest you try easier exercises before you start with this one. This is about as hairy as these problems get, ever.

The derivative of $y$ is another function, $y'$, and in this case it will be a fraction. More or less like $y$ itself, but with different numerator and denominator. You want to know for what $x$-values this fraction is equal to $0$ (those $x$-values are the same as the $x$-values for which $y$ itself is at its highest or lowest, more or less), so you solve the equation $y' = 0$. I assume you will get two solutions, both of them containing $a$ and $b$.

Once you have those, you put them in for $x$ in the original $y$-expression. You now have two expressions, both depending on (that means *contains*, in some form or another) $a$ and $b$. One of them should be equal to $-5$, the other to $4$. This is all you need to calculate $a$ and $b$ so that the maximum value of the function is $4$, and the minimum value is $-5$.